# Where can I find a specification for the Flash debugging protocol?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, debugging, specifications

Where can I find a specification for the Flash/ActionScript debugging protocol? I would imagine that the protocol is public, as there are plenty of open source debuggers; however, if it's not, a list of resources to reference would be greatly appreciated.

If you're curious, I'm implementing an ActionScript Bytecode (ABC) to [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) compiler, and I'd like to make the resulting assemblies debuggable via standard flash debuggers.

Answer (score 2):

The Open Flash Debugger project might help you out.  You might still need to do some reverse engineering, but it describes many of the debugger messages sent back and forth between the debug player and the debugger.

http://osflash.org/ofd